# Getting MYSQL best search results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table which contain meta records. I need best search results from records.

Suppos If I search in table with following keywords :

```
Beautiful well-maintained Remodeled
```

Then my result should be this type:

Firstly all records contains all three keywords,
Second records contain any two records
and last records contain any one keywords.

I have tried fulltext search and Like query but I didn't get results.

Comment: Can you show us your query?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279574/if-search-string-full-match-then-record-should-come-first-otherwise-it-should-be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the matches per record ond order by this:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    mytable.*,
    case when lower(col) like '%beautiful%' then 1 else 0 end +
    case when lower(col) like '%well-maintained%' then 1 else 0 end +
    case when lower(col) like '%remodeled%' then 1 else 0 end as matches
  from mytable
)
where matches > 0
order by matches desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [PHP explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get each word separated and adjust my SQL query accordingly using AND and OR statements using Likes:

```
$keywords = explode(" ", $_REQUEST['q']);
$sql_query = $dbh->prepare("QUERY");
$i = 0;
foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $sql_query->bindParam($i, $keyword);
}
```

I know this code alone wont work, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using LIKE

Has 3:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE <column> LIKE '%Beautiful%'
AND <column> LIKE '%well-maintained%'
AND <column> LIKE '%Remodeled%'
```

Any Two:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE ( <column> LIKE '%Beautiful%' AND <column> LIKE '%well-maintained%' )
OR ( <column> LIKE '%Remodeled%' AND <column> LIKE '%well-maintained%' )
OR ( <column> LIKE '%Beautiful%' AND <column> LIKE '%Remodeled%' )
```

Any One:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE <column> LIKE '%Beautiful%' 
OR <column> LIKE '%Remodeled%'
OR <column> LIKE '%Beautiful%'
```

Using Regex for any match:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> REGEXP '(.*)Remodeled(.*)|(.*)well-maintained(.*)|(.*)Beautiful(.*)'
```